# android studio not launching

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have downloaded the zip and extracted it to a file and I have eclipse, but everytime i try launching android studio an error pops up saying,

```
Failed to execute child process "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" (No such file or directory)
```

I am a beginner to both coding and ubuntu and I want to create an android app.

Answer (score 2):

Install Android Studio with this command in Terminal :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

And for more info see this:

https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: that's what I did, First I installed the zip off the website, then I extracted the file into a folder, then i did that command, and it then i try opening it and it gives me the message I stated above.

Comment: You do not need to install zip from web. Just run that 3 command in terminal. And then simply run the Android Studio. It take the PPA from the Repo (So no need to download from web). After that... check that you have installed java correctly and set JAVA_HOME as environment variable. You can see this link for that. [See Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17827697/2533809)

Comment: I did all that you said and was trying to set JAVA_HOME as the environment variable by using the link you provided, but once I type the sudo nano /etc/environment and press enter, it says sudo: nano: command not found

Comment: nano is just a editor. You can use any editor like "gedit",
if nano is not install then use gedit or any other editor.
or install nano use this command -- "sudo apt-get install nano"

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really bad for this, I installed nano, and i used it to append JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle by opening up nano by typing, sudo nano /etc/environment and then pressing ^R and type JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle but then it says "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" not found

Comment: try to remove java and your android-studio once. and reinstall with above commands!

Comment: use:(1) sudo apt-get remove android-studio 
And then (2)    sudo apt-get remove java*

Comment: ok i did that and now I can open the application but it won't let me do much because I need to download the sdk, which I did and is currently a zip file under downloads, I don't want to mess it up again so what should i do next?

Comment: Ok, now you want to do this thing... Just add the SDK that you want.... see official link of android developer-->>
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Comment: is there a detailed video or link that shows step by step instructions because everything i look at, is not useful or is a different version that what i have (14.04) I am a beginner and am getting frustrated with all the time im spending on just trying to install the program

Comment: Video for fresh installation of Android Studio :-      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjJxwO5NIJk

Comment: I have tried following that video many times over and over and once  it gets to the part where you use the terminal to open android studio, in the video there is supposed to be a "Complete Installation" popup (3:00 in the video), but I dont get the popup, so I just skipped that and went on to the next part where android studio opens up and there is a "Select SDKs" popup (3:45)which i dont get, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I know this has been awhile, but I have tried followed your instructions, and I cannot get android studio to launch

Comment: @Turtle ,  You can also refer this sites too.  https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/   &  https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio